# SublimeText 3, how to navigate between files in project

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm new to SublimeText (migrated from TextMate) and it's awesome.
But I'm familiar with JetBrains IDE and I need functionality to quickly open a file/class in a project. SublimeText provides cool features, like open symbol anywhere, goto anything and so on, but I can't find anything to open just files in a project.
When I'm working on a big project – goto anything and similar are not suit for me.

For example, I have a class named Data. When I'm trying to open that class with 'goto anything/symbol in project' – I got a lot of variables and methods in the list, because 'data' is pretty common word in programming.

So, I'm trying to achieve functionality to open only classes/files, without searching inside of them (like JetBrains Navigate -> Class). Is there any built-in functionality, or I need to write a custom plugin for my needs?

Comment: Have you tried `ctrl+p` for Windows/Linux or `cmd+p` for OS X? This should just bring up the files in the project, not the symbols. This is the GoTo anything functionality so I wasn't really sure, but it should do what you want. Unlike an IDE, ST doesn't just look at the file name. If that's what you want, you will likely need to write/find a plugin. However, you would still need some way to differentiate between different files with the same name (which will likely be similar to the goto anything functionality).

Comment: Unfortunately no, at least in sublimetext3 it's bind to action 'go to anything'.

Comment: Since it seems like you want some language aware generation for the file list, you will need to write/find a plugin. Though, if it's leveraging the quick panel, a fuzzy matching algorithm will still be used. Though depending on how you structure in information in the panel, it may just look at the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I threw the following together so you have an idea of something you can do. It might work well enough for you, if not, perhaps you can build off of it. This will grab every file, so perhaps you will want to add some sort of ignore patterns. If I recall, JetBrains works like that. For one shortcut it searches everything, for the other, just classes (well indexed files is probably more accurate)

```
import sublime_plugin
import os

class FileNameBasedOpen(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.input_content = []
        for folder in self.window.folders():
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
                for f in files:
                    self.input_content.append([f, root])

        self.window.show_quick_panel(self.input_content, self.on_select)

    def on_select(self, index):
        if index == -1:
            return
        else:
            f = os.path.join(self.input_content[index][1], self.input_content[index][0])
            self.window.open_file(f)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, man. I think we can stop here: i'm check it when I'm come back to my computer. Just thought there could be a better built-in functionality. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just figured that out. CMD + T, like TextMate.

Comment: Just fyi, `cmd+t` and `cmd+p` do the same thing (unless you or one of the plugins you have installed has changed it). You can verify this by entering `sublime.log_commands(True)` into the ST console.